# Fatal error with a manual clear screen function

Tags: c

I'm finding a proper solution for clearing the screen without include conio.h, and [found this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10515/#msg49080).

I use CPU *AMD Athlon X64 3200+* and Windows XP SP3

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

void Clrscr(void);

int main(void) {
    puts("Are you ready?");
    getchar();
    Clrscr();
    puts("See? The screen is cleared ^_^");
    return 0;
}

void Clrscr(void) {
    HANDLE hStdOut;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    DWORD count;
    DWORD cellCount;
    COORD homeCoords={0,0};
    hStdOut=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(hStdOut==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;
    if(!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut,&csbi))
        return;
    if(!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut,(TCHAR)' ',cellCount,homeCoords,&count))
        return;
    if(!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hStdOut,csbi.wAttributes,cellCount,homeCoords,&count))
        return;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut,homeCoords);
}
```

But when I test it in Pelles C IDE I get the error "**C:\Program Files\PellesC\Include\Win\winnt.h(559): fatal error #1014: #error: "No target architecture".**"

Then I double click on that line and it get me to *winnt.h* and highlight row 559, here is a piece of code with include row 559

```
#if defined(_68K_) || defined(_MPPC_) || defined(_M_IA64) || defined(_M_AMD64)

#define Int32x32To64(a,b)  (((__int64)((long)(a))) * ((__int64)((long)(b))))
#define UInt32x32To64(a,b)  (((unsigned __int64)((unsigned int)(a))) * ((unsigned __int64)((unsigned int)(b))))

#define Int64ShllMod32(a,b)  (((unsigned __int64)(a)) << (b))
#define Int64ShraMod32(a,b)  (((__int64)(a)) >> (b))
#define Int64ShrlMod32(a,b)  (((unsigned __int64)(a)) >> (b))

#elif defined(_M_IX86)

#define Int32x32To64(a, b)  ((__int64)(((__int64)((long)(a))) * ((long)(b))))
#define UInt32x32To64(a, b) ((unsigned __int64)(((unsigned __int64)((unsigned int)(a))) * ((unsigned int)(b))))

ULONGLONG NTAPI Int64ShllMod32(ULONGLONG, DWORD);
LONGLONG NTAPI Int64ShraMod32(LONGLONG, DWORD);
ULONGLONG NTAPI Int64ShrlMod32(ULONGLONG, DWORD);

__inline ULONGLONG NTAPI Int64ShllMod32(ULONGLONG Value, DWORD ShiftCount) {
    __asm {
        mov ecx, ShiftCount
        mov eax, dword ptr[Value]
        mov edx, dword ptr[Value +4]
        shld edx, eax, cl
        shl eax, cl
    }
}

__inline LONGLONG NTAPI Int64ShraMod32(LONGLONG Value, DWORD ShiftCount) {
    __asm {
        mov ecx, ShiftCount
        mov eax, dword ptr[Value]
        mov edx, dword ptr[Value +4]
        shrd eax, edx, cl
        sar edx, cl
    }
}

__inline ULONGLONG NTAPI Int64ShrlMod32(ULONGLONG Value, DWORD ShiftCount) {
    __asm {
        mov ecx, ShiftCount
        mov eax, dword ptr[Value]
        mov edx, dword ptr[Value +4]
        shrd eax, edx, cl
        shr edx, cl
    }
}

#elif defined(RC_INVOKED)
#else
#error "No target architecture" //line 559
#endif /* machine */
```

I don't know what is going on, I'm new to C programming and I'm just trying to make my coding style more standard.
Please let me know what's happened and how to fix this.
Thanks for reading my question!

Comment: It seems that this question is really an issue with your compiler and not the program itself.

Comment: It looks like you project settings/makefile are not set up correctly.

Comment: Thank for the advise, but when I paste the code to Code:Blocks and run, it get a ton of words that I really don't understand. Here: ""TESTa - Debug": The compiler's setup (GNU GCC Compiler) is invalid, so Code::Blocks cannot find/run the compiler.
Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?! (Do you have a compiler installed?)
Goto "Settings->Compiler...->Global compiler settings->GNU GCC Compiler->Toolchain executables" and fix the compiler's setup.
Skipping...
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date)."

Comment: After I follow the instruction and re-build, it promp another error: "||=== Build: Debug in TESTa (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 can't create obj\Debug\Test.o||No such file or directory|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s)) ===|
"

Comment: I'd probably just do `system("cls");`.

Comment: @ace: But using system(...) funtion is very creepy.

Comment: To compile a Windows code in PellesC requires Microsoft extensions enablled. If you're using the IDE open project options dialog and select Microsofte extensions. If you're compiling from command line add the switch /Ze to the compiler command.